# Do the same powerups in Splatoon-gear stack?

Tags: splatoon

In the game Splatoon, if you have different gear (shoes, shirt, hat) with the same powerup (let's say Attack+) have any effect? The cat says no, but other sources say they have. What is it really?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some abilities are stackable (13), other are not (11). Non-stackable are only obtainable as primary ability. Stackable can be obtained as both primary and secondary ability.

In this image you see the difference between the stackable and non-stackable ones:

[image: Abilities]

The first are stackable (purple), the second (blue) are not. So the cat is probably talking about the non-stackable ones. [Source](http://splatoon.wikia.com/wiki/Ability)

edit: please note that the source is messing things up in the textual part. They say there are 13 non-stackable abilities, but there are 11 in their list below. I adjusted my answer here to fix that.

Comment: I can definitely confirm this. I've had 3 times *Ink Saver (Main)*, allowing me to use my Charger more efficiently. Then I exchanged my gear, leaving me with only 1 *Ink Saver (Main)*. My play was pretty bad then, because I kept running out of ink at the worst possible times. So abilities **do** stack. However, some abilities obviously **don't** stack, such as the one that eliminates damage from walking over enemy ink or the one that allows for a stealthy super jump.

Comment: Another point is that stackable items provide diminishing returns. Stacking the 2nd slot with the same ability is only 50% as effective and the 3rd one is only 25%.

Comment: Note that primary and secondary abilities give you different stats, regardless if they are stackable or not. For example, damage up primary gives you 10%, secondary gives you 3% (approximate values for example). And as previously mentioned, teach.hey will have diminishing effects as you stack more. The first Damage Up Primary applied gives a 9% damage boost, but 2 give ~8.25% each, and 3 give ~7.45%